# Selecting edges and vertices of a Solid3D entity in Eyeshot 11

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, cad, eyeshot

I have a Solid3D object inside a block and need to select its edges.

I tried:

```
viewport.SelectionFilterMode = selectionFilterType.Edge; 
viewport.ActionMode = actionType.SelectByPick;
```

As the block is treated as a single object, doing so would select the whole Solid3D object.

Could you suggest me a solution that I could use to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set viewportLayout.AssemblySelectionMode to assemblySelectionType.Leaf:

```
viewportLayout.AssemblySelectionMode = ViewportLayout.assemblySelectionType.Leaf;
```

and viewportLayout.SelectionFilterMode to selectionFilterType.Edge:

```
viewportLayout.SelectionFilterMode = selectionFilterType.Edge;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the BlockReference as current.

```
viewportLayout.Entities.SetCurrent(myBlockRef)
```